# Date Interval Counts

Tags: sql

I have been searching around for an example on how to group the count of date intervals that are exclusive.

One way it can be done is this way:

```
 DECLARE @tmp TABLE(cnt INT)

 INSERT INTO @tmp(cnt)
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ProblemCnt
 FROM Problems
 WHERE Closed IS NULL
 AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) <=10)

 INSERT INTO @tmp(cnt)
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ProblemCnt
 FROM Problems
 WHERE Closed IS NULL
 AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) >10
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) <=20)

 INSERT INTO @tmp(cnt)
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ProblemCnt
 FROM Problems
 WHERE Closed IS NULL
 AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) >20
     AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) <=30)

 SELECT cnt FROM @tmp
```

Problem is with the way it's done above is it is not as dynamic as needed and it is needed to go up to 300 days.
So, there would be a lot of selects and inserts. Not very proficient.

Also, I have been looking at something like this:

```
 dateadd(day, 5 + (datediff(day, 0, Opened) / 5) * 5, 0)
```

This is just a sample of a possibility that needs adjustment.

Does anyone have a better suggestion on how to achieve this without using the temp table above?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could round the difference in days down (or up) to the nearest 10, then group by this interval:

```
SELECT  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) / 10.0) * 10 AS Interval,
        COUNT(*) AS ProblemCnt
FROM    Problems
WHERE   Closed IS NULL
AND     Opened >= DATEADD(DAY, -300, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
AND     Opened < GETDATE()
GROUP BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) / 10.0) * 10;
```

I have also changed your where clause slightly, your current WHERE clause is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). e.g. using

```
WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) < 10
```

Means that the function is evaluated for every record, and any indexes on `Opened` can't be used, but switching this to

```
WHERE   Opened >= DATEADD(DAY, -300, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
AND     Opened < GETDATE()
```

Means that DATEADD is evaluated once at the start of the query (since `GETDATE()` is treated as a constant), and because `Opened` is being compared directly indexes can now be used.

Comment: This is a very thoughtful solution. It even brings back the interval which would be very helpful. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

it can be done with a simple loop as below

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(cnt INT)

DECLARE @T INT 
SET @T = 0

WHILE (@T <=290)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @tmp(cnt)
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS ProblemCnt
    FROM Problems
    WHERE Closed IS NULL
    AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) >@T
       AND DATEDIFF(DAY, Opened, GETDATE()) <=@T + 10)

    SET @T = @T + 10

END

SELECT cnt FROM @tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your solution works great but I tend to avoid loops, cursors, etc in sql when I can. But +1.